# How to pass an array of templates to an Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a newbie with Angular and I wanted to create a carousel as shared component. The DOM of this component is based on latest version of Bootstrap and I'd like to inject templates by the caller.

For example I have a carouselComponent's DOM like below:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <!-- foreach template passing by the caller
        <div data-index="0"></div>
        -->
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <!-- foreach template passing by the caller
        <div class="carousel-item" data-index="0"></div>
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So in my head I think something like:

```
<carousel>
    <template-list>
        <div dataIndex="0">Ciao Mondo!</div>
        <div dataIndex="1">Hello World!</div>
        <div dataIndex="2">Hola Mundo!</div>
    </template-list>
</carousel>
```

all carousel-indicators are calculated in base of the template list and the carouse-inner is filled with all templates (in template list) wrapped by a div.carousel-item.

But I didn't find something for this problem.
My need born to fulfill the need to uncouple component and logic and so I can reuse that component.

Thanks so much to all people! :)

Comment: There is already a carousel component developed for bootstrap with Angular. You can take a look at how they implemented it, because I think their approach is best. https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel

Answer (score 0):

Angular component will have only one Template defined in the component.ts file

but in the html file you can add sub templates using [ngtemplate](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) and switch them based on your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-html
**TS**

```
   array=[ 
            '<div dataIndex="0">Ciao Mondo!</div>',
            '<div dataIndex="1">Hello World!</div>',
            '<div dataIndex="2">Hola Mundo!</div>'
            ].toString().replace(/,/g, '');
```

**HTML**

```
    <div [innerHTML]="array"></div>
```

Comment: This isn't an elegant solution! :D
...and if I have to bind some events like click? (I think to a login/register's form into the carousel)

Comment: well you didn't specify that in your question. This solves your original question

Answer (score 0):

Passing HTML as input is not a good idea as you might need to bind some data later, so you should leave rendering on child component but you can pass data from parent component, So You can create a list of your desired objects and then pass it to your component as an input:

in parent.component.ts:

```
templateList = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "text": "Ciao Mondo!"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Hello World!"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "Hola Mundo!"
  }
]
```

and in parent.component.html:

```
<carousel [templateList]="templateList">
</carousel>
```

in carousel.component.ts:

```
@Input()
templateList: any[];
```

and in carousel.component.html:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <div *ngFor="let data of templateList" [attr.data-index]="data.id"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div *ngFor="let data of templateList" class="carousel-item" [attr.data-index]="data.id">{{data.text}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok... but... I'd like to fill the carousel with a login/register form and I can switch form in base to the user's need: login or register.

so I'd like to fill it with templates to render...

Comment: you can have a separate login component which u can redirect to or call based on ngIf, having them all in same component will increase the coupling which apparently you want to reduct